# How to delete multiple matches in bash

Tags: bash, awk, sed, non-greedy

I have multiple files with the following structure:

```
(Genome1_Sample4A_protein_Genome1_Sample4A_132_2:0.0060449,(Genome1_Sample5A_protein_Genome1_Sample5A_30_12:1e-06,(Genome1_Sample1B_protein_Genome1_Sample1B_99_2:1e-06,Genome1_Sample6A_protein_Genome1_Sample6A_295_2:0.00366292)n2:0.00370314)n1:0.0060449)n0;
```

I would like to delete in each of them what comes between "_protein" and ":". So the output would be as follow:

```
(Genome1_Sample4A:0.0060449,(Genome1_Sample5A:1e-06,(Genome1_Sample1B:1e-06,Genome1_Sample6A:0.00366292)n2:0.00370314)n1:0.0060449)n0;
```

I have tried to use sed and awk:

```
sed -i 's/_protein.*:/:/g' tree1.txt

sed -i 's/_protein.*_[[:digit:]]*:/:/g' tree1.txt

awk '{gsub(/\_protein*:/,":");}1' tree1.txt
```

But any of these codes gave me the desired output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.*` is [greedy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2301298/21926), so use this instead:

```
sed 's/_protein[^:]*:/:/g' tree1.txt
```

Output:

```
(Genome1_Sample4A:0.0060449,(Genome1_Sample5A:1e-06,(Genome1_Sample1B:1e-06,Genome1_Sample6A:0.00366292)n2:0.00370314)n1:0.0060449)n0;
```